# Как открывать Chrome через селениум с открытыми до этого вкладками?

Tags: python, selenium

Возможно ли открывать браузер (Chrome) через селениум с открытыми мною до этого вкладками. Если можно по подскажите как это сделать пожалуйста.

Comment: фактически можно просто активировать сохранение закладок в хроме и открыть по обычному, опишите свою проблему точнее

Comment: точнее: открываю браузер, открываю какую-нибудь вкладку закрываю. Запускаю программу, открывается браузер без вкладок. Нужно с вкладками

Comment: включи просто в настройках хрома сохранение вкладок

Comment: когда гуглил как это пофиксить наткнулся на такое, не помогло